# Backing up VirtualBox VMs

Tags: backup, virtualbox, disaster-recovery, virtual-machines, snapshot

Does anyone have a good complete strategy for backing up a bunch of virtual machines running under VirtualBox?

I intend to run a handful of virtual machines on a single hardware platform and back them up nightly to external disks, which will be taken off site every weekend in rotation.

(Just to clarify, I don't intend to shut the machines down during this process, if I can avoid it)

Am I right in thinking I can just write a script which, each night, creates a snapshot, copies the 'main' disk image to the external media, then removes the snapshot again?

Better ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the VirtualBox 2.2+, there is a feature that allows you to import/export VM's in the Open Virtualization format. This format puts everything together for you in one nice file.

- To **import**

  - From the GUI: *File -> Import Appliance*
  - From the console:

    > VBoxManage import SomeName.ovf
- To **export**

  - From the GUI: *File -> Export Appliance*
  - From the console:

    > VBoxManage export "Name of VM" -o SomeName.ovf

Comment: i dont know how import/export works, but i have some problems to run same VM on Windows to MAC, but I got it to work after changing something in XML file

Comment: Looks exceptionally handy, especially if it's scriptable -- but does it work without shutting the machine down?

Answer (score 0):

if you going shut your VMs down, just copy everything without snapshots, also keep in mind that you need to copy .xml files as well

Comment: I wasn't planning to shut down the machines to back them up, as they will be running customer visible services, however I can probably arrange a brief window to do this if it's the better way...

Answer (score 0):

maybe halting the VM is good enough to back the files up?!